# ssh not using /etc/hosts to resolve hostnames

Tags: centos, ssh, hostname

This is how my /etc/hosts file looks in /etc/hosts:

[image]

If I try to connect to one of these machines with ssh:

```
ssh -p 22 ramy@Ramy-MacBook
```

I get an error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname Ramy-MacBook: Name or service unknown
```

If I use the IP address it works.

Comment: First the IP, then the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the default entries in the first two line. You mixed up the order of hosts/IPs.

Try this instead:

```
192.168.0.18      ramy-VirtualBox     
192.168.0.8       Ramy-MacBook
```

Answer (score 2):

That's normal, you need to write first the ip then the name, in your case:

```
192.168.0.8       Ramy-MacBook
192.168.0.18      ramy-VirtualBox
```